# Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException when running an EJB sample project

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception, ejb, ejb-3.0

I am new to EJB and hence I was executing a sample EJB project as in the tutorial [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbnc.html)

Here's how  the beans look:

**Converter.java**

```
package converter.ejb;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface Converter {
    public BigDecimal dollarToYen(BigDecimal dollars);
    public BigDecimal yenToEuro(BigDecimal yen);
}
```

**ConverterBean.java**

```
package converter.ejb;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class ConverterBean {

    private BigDecimal yenRate = new BigDecimal("115.3100");
    private BigDecimal euroRate = new BigDecimal("0.0071");

    public BigDecimal dollarToYen(BigDecimal dollars) {
        BigDecimal result = dollars.multiply(yenRate);
        return result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
    }

    public BigDecimal yenToEuro(BigDecimal yen) {
        BigDecimal result = yen.multiply(euroRate);
        return result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
    }
}
```

**ConverterClient.java**

```
package converter.ejb;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

public class ConverterClient {

    @EJB
    private static Converter converter;

    public ConverterClient(String[] args) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConverterClient client = new ConverterClient(args);
        client.doConversion();
    }

    public void doConversion() {
        try {
            BigDecimal param = new BigDecimal("100.00");
            BigDecimal yenAmount = converter.dollarToYen(param);

            System.out.println("$" + param + " is " + yenAmount
                    + " Yen.");
            BigDecimal euroAmount = converter.yenToEuro(yenAmount);
            System.out.println(yenAmount + " Yen is " + euroAmount
                    + " Euro.");

            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Caught an unexpected exception!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a web client which is a JSP Page: **converterweb.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="converter.ejb.Converter,
            java.math.*, javax.naming.*"%>    
 <%!
    private Converter converter = null;
    public void jspInit() {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            converter = (Converter)
                    ic.lookup(Converter.class.getName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Couldn’t create converter bean."+
                    ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
        public void jspDestroy() {
        converter = null;
    }
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Converter</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">
        <h1>Converter</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Enter an amount to convert:</p>
        <form method="get">
            <input type="text" name="amount" size="25">
            <br>
            <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>

        <%
            String amount = request.getParameter("amount");
            if ( amount != null && amount.length() > 0 ) {
                BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(amount);

                BigDecimal yenAmount = converter.dollarToYen(d);
        %>
        <p>
        <%= amount %> dollars are  <%= yenAmount %>  Yen.
        <p>
        <%
                BigDecimal euroAmount =
                        converter.yenToEuro(yenAmount);
        %>
        <%= amount %> Yen are <%= euroAmount %>  Euro.
        <%
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I get a NullPointerException whenever I try to execute this project. I use Websphere application server. Can someone please shed some light as to why this is happening and how I can rectify it?

**Edit:** Error log

```
[12/10/12 14:21:26:956 IST] 0000001f webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[/converterweb.jsp]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm._jsp._converterweb._jspService(_converterweb.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:763)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
```

Comment: where do you get the NPE? i assume in the line where you call `converter.dollarToYen(param)`, right?

Comment: @Yevgeniy I am not sure where the NPE is. Websphere error log points to the Java file which is the conversion of the JSP file. My JSP is converterweb.jsp, and WAS points to line 118 of converterweb.java which I cannot open.

Comment: If you don't post your trace error log it's hard to "guess" what your problem is.

Comment: Error 500 means you have a server side error. Please paste the error found in your server logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is full of errors:

- EJB dependency injection works for components managed by container. Your ConverterClient has no annotations on it (I assume you didn't do any additional EJB configuration in the xml descriptors). So container is not aware of it and cannot do injection.
- Your converter is declared as static. This will not work.
- You are trying to access a bean declared as @LocalBean (which means it exposes no-interface view) via Remote interface. This will not work too. Try using ConverterBean directly or avoid @LocalBean and use @Remote(Converter.class) instead.

Maybe I've missed something. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I think this is not the explanation about what OP has asked.

Comment: @Andrey I have followed this tutorial since I am new to EJB and trsuted it to work. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbnc.html

Comment: @Rajath there are important points in this tutorial that differ from your post:
- ConverterBean is not marked with @LocalBean;
- ConverterBean implements Converter interface.

If you fix that it should work I suppose.

Comment: @AndreyPolunin Thanks for pointing it out! Corrected it, but still not working.

Comment: @Rajath Did you update your post according to the changes? I'm asking because you removed LocalBean annotation but you still didn't make ConverterBean to implement Converter. You should either put additional annotation Remote(Converter.class) on the ConverterBean or make ConverterBean implement Converter. It can be the cause of your problem I suppose.

Comment: @AndreyPolunin Worked! Thanks much! I made ConverterBean implement Converter. But did not work when I put the annotation `@Remote(Converter.class)`. Any idea why? Curious to know.

Comment: @Rajath I think you can find the answer in the EJB 3.1 spec. I've just consulted with it. Look at the section 4.4.2.2 (Session bean exposing multiple client views). According to it the problem might be in that the JNDI name you tried to use to find the bean wasn't tied to it without @Remote(Converter.class) annotation.